# Google Cloud IoT Core end-to-end prototype example question (reading sensor data from phone to Cloud IoT Core)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, iot

Google gives a nice example on how to implement an end-to-end IoT prototype using their cloud platform and a phone as a sensor device at https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/resources/building-an-end-to-end-iot-prototype.
Using the instructions it is possible to read phone sensor data using a webapp which will then relay it to the Google IoT Core. The example/documentation does not give any information about the webapp. I am trying to understand how the webapp works and tried searching for examples, but could not find any.
The question is: How can I create a similar webapp that can read sensor data from a phone and then send it to the Google IoT Core? I do not need detailed instructions, but I would like to know where to start the search.

Comment: the system flow he will be phone or sensor send data to google cloud IoT Core (topic -> cloud function -> database). And after that, you can create a web app that will read data from the database and so on.

Comment: The application you are referring to is a web based. https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/resources/building-an-end-to-end-iot-prototype#authenticate_your_phone is web based app. If you want to create a similar app, this question should be addressed to a web/mobile app developer.

Answer (score 0):

The phone connects to Cloud IoT Core, which authenticates the device and publishes live data to the telemetry topic as is depicted in [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/resources/building-an-end-to-end-iot-prototype). There is no web app in the middle, Cloud IoT collects the data and publishes it to [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) (telemetry topic), then you can develop an app that receives and processes the published telemetry data from Pub/Sub.

I suggest you to take a look at the following codelabs for further references:

- [Using IoT Core to Stream Heart Rate Data](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/iotcore-heartrate/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)
- [Building a Serverless Data Pipeline: IoT to Analytics](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/iot-data-pipeline/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

As you can see, both approaches populate the data within [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) and use two different services to get and process the data: [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions). Within each codelab there are examples of the app between Pub/Sub and BigQuery.